# Any way to remove duplicates to this "For XML Path" query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.DESCRIPTION,
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + col.CUST_ORDER_ID 
           FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE col
           WHERE col.PART_ID = p.ID 
           ORDER BY col.CUST_ORDER_ID 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Customer Orders],
    STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ql.QUOTE_ID  
           FROM QUOTE_LINE ql
           WHERE ql.PART_ID = p.ID 
           ORDER BY ql.QUOTE_ID 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') As Quotes
FROM
    PART p
GROUP BY
    p.ID, p.DESCRIPTION
```

I end up with many duplicate "Customer Orders".  I tried adding "DISTINCT" i.e. "Stuff((Select DISTINCT" but I get the error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified".  There's already an "Order By col.CUST_ORDER_ID" in the statement so I guess I don't understand.  Can anyone provide me with a suggestion and possibly and explanation?  Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: When using DISTINCT, all items in the ORDER BY must be in list of fields part of the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select p.ID,
  p.DESCRIPTION,
  Stuff((Select distinct '; ' + col.CUST_ORDER_ID From CUST_ORDER_LINE col
  Where col.PART_ID = p.ID Order By '; ' + col.CUST_ORDER_ID For Xml Path('')), 1, 1,
  '') [Customer Orders],
  Stuff((Select distinct  '; ' + ql.QUOTE_ID From QUOTE_LINE ql
  Where ql.PART_ID = p.ID Order By '; ' + ql.QUOTE_ID For Xml Path('')), 1, 1,
  '') As Quotes
From PART p
Group By p.ID,
  p.DESCRIPTION
```

Simpy use ';'+ use in order by column with distinct clause.order by column and selected column data must be same.